# Java Palindrome - Time & Space Complexity

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, complexity

Which of these three methods is the most efficient?

Also, what is the time & space complexity of each?

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static boolean isStringBased(String word) {
        if (word == null || "".equals(word)) {
            return false;
        }
        String lowerCasedWord = word.toLowerCase();
        int i = 0;
        int j = lowerCasedWord.length() - 1;

        while (i < j) {
            if (lowerCasedWord.charAt(i) != lowerCasedWord.charAt(j))
                return false;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindromeRecursive(String input) {
        if(input.length() == 0 || input.length() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if(input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length()-1)) {
            return isPalindromeRecursive(input.substring(1, input.length()-1));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindromeIterative(String input) {
        boolean retValue = false;
        int length = input.length();
        for( int i = 0; i < length/2; i++ ) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(length-i-1)) {
                retValue = true;
            }
        }
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: `isPalindromeIterative("override")`: true.

Comment: What terrible programming practices are these? The functions are not named similarly, the checks on the input / word are different for each, unexplained and incorrectly implemented algorithms. Yuk.

Answer (score 2):

First solution requires O(1) space and O(n) complexity.

The last one looks to be less than 100% efficient, because you could directly return false when you find out it is not a palindrome, but it continues until the loop ends.

Comment: Why did someone put a downvote (and its not -1)? I thought the purpose of the code review is to help people.

Comment: (@PacificNW_Lover Up to this comment, nobody downvoted this answer. Your question has been down-voted once, with no up-vote. By rights, somebody found it *not useful* (**as it was at the time of the vote**).)

Answer (score 2):

You present undocumented code
(yours, truly? `StringBased` looks *different*).

let me try and just code it more tersely, correcting the iterative variety:

```java
/** check a <code>CharSequence</code> to be a <em>palindrome</em> */
static interface Palindrome {
    /** @return <code>true</code> if <code>word</code>
     *  is a <em>palindrome</em> else <code>false</code> */
    boolean isPalindrome(CharSequence word);

    static class StringBased implements Palindrome {
        public boolean isPalindrome(CharSequence word) {
            if (word == null || 0 == word.length())
                return false;
            String lowerCasedWord = word.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0, j = word.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
                if (lowerCasedWord.charAt(i) != lowerCasedWord.charAt(j))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    static class Recursive implements Palindrome {
        public boolean isPalindrome(CharSequence input) {
            int last;
            return input.length() <= 1
                || input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(last = input.length()-1)
                   && isPalindrome(input.substring(1, last));
        }
    }
    static class Iterative implements Palindrome {
        public boolean isPalindrome(CharSequence input) {
            int length = input.length();
            for( int i = 0; i < length/2; i++ )
                if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(length-i-1))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Palindrome[]checkers = {
                new StringBased(),
                new Recursive(),
                new Iterative()
            };
        String [] checks = { "", "a", "aa", "ab", "Aba", "abc", "aaba", };
        System.out.print('\t');
        for (String check: checks)
            System.out.print("\t\"" + check + '"');
        for (Palindrome checker: checkers) {
            System.out.print('\n' + checker.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":\t");
            for (String check: checks)
                System.out.print(checker.isPalindrome(check) + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

`StringBased` still is different (`Evitareti` is `isPalindromeIterative()`):

> ```
>               ""      "a"     "aa"    "ab"    "Aba"   "abc"   "aaba"
> StringBased:  false   true    true    false   true    false   false   
> Recursive:    true    true    true    false   false   false   false   
> Iterative:    true    true    true    false   false   false   false   
> Evitareti:    false   false   true    false   false   false   true
> ```

`StringBased` and `Recursive` use O(n) additional space.
With respect to time,

1. **DON'T assume**: model & **measure**
   (using a framework, microbenchmarking where appropriate (e.g. here))
2. your mileage **will** vary

Comment: "production strength" implementations *without instance data* should be *singletons*.

Comment: Nice rewrite. What I'm missing here is the fact that `Palindrome` is not a **verb**. It should really be `PalindromeChecker` or something similar. Terse is fine, but removing the braces is not (this is subjective, but I guess if > 90% of devs agree on it, that you need to make it explicit in your answer that most don't agree).

Comment: (I learned coding with each line adding 2.5 grams to the program, and the quality of rubber bands important to the mental balance of a coder. PalindromeChecker was the name of the abstract class when I first typed this… (I tried renaming the predicate to `is()` when I shortened the interface name - didn't work for me.))